# Responsive Quicktime player

Tags: javascript, css, quicktime, .mov

Hi I'm trying to make a Quicktime player responsive but I fail on each attempt, don't know if this is possible. 
Is there any way to do it with css, or I need any javascript to properly do it?
The container of the player response when I resize the browser but when doing this I only see a part of the video. 
The video format is in `.mov`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it's quite simple. In [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_HTML/QTScripting_HTML_Document/ScriptingHTML.html) link you have all the documentation of the Quicktime player.
You can use javascript with `ac_quicktime.js` or use a simple embed/object, the embed/object uses a lot ot attributes that you can find on the link that i put previously.
Here's an example to embed a video that fits to the 100% height and width o the container.

```
<embed src="#urlOfTheVideo" HEIGHT="100%" WIDTH="100%" TYPE="video/quicktime" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" AUTOPLAY="true" CONTROLLER="true" SCALE = "Aspect" />
```

The most important attribute here are the width and height, but to maintain the aspect of the video it's very important to add the attribute `SCALE="Aspect"` you can also use `ToFit` as value which will fit the parent container.

Hope to someone find this usefull

Comment: Thanks a lot! Best way is to use ac_quicktime.js and the tag 
<script language="javascript">
    QT_WriteOBJECT('../Movies/MyMovie.mov' , '100%', '100%', '', 'AUTOPLAY', 'True', 'SCALE', 'Aspect') ;
</script>
in order to keep the compatibily with IE I think.